# WAMP - SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is required

Tags: php

I would like configure my wamp-mail-server. In file php.ini have I this configuration :

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP =  localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http:  //php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = kubus.martin@gmail.com
```

My code in php file :

`< ?php
mail('kubus.martin@gmail.com', 'Hello!', 'test email');
? >`

and i become this alert: 
SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is required

I don`t have any password. I am using wamp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Whoever configured SMTP on your server did it *correctly* since it's requiring a username and password.
2. Ask whoever that was for the username and password you should use.
3. Go get [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) because PHP's built in `mail()` function is awful and can't handle SMTP-Auth.